# Django views.static in urls?

Tags: python, django, url, static, python-sphinx

I'm trying to setup Sphinx with Django.

Sphinx generates the html files, and links between them based on file/directory structure.

Since Sphinx only generates static files, I have to setup my urls with `django.views.static`

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import path
from django.views import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', static.serve, {'document_root': settings.DOCS_ROOT, 'path': 'index.html'}, name='index'),
    path('(<path>.html)', static.serve, {'document_root': settings.DOCS_ROOT}, name='static.file.serve'),
]
```

This serves the `index.html` just fine, but returns 404 on other templates.

Comment: Show us views.py.

Comment: There are no views.py. This directly fetches the html files generated by Sphinx. Found a soultion though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel stupid posting this, and finding the answer right away.
I just changed the last url slightly.

```
path('<path>', static.serve, {'document_root': settings.DOCS_ROOT}, name='static.file.serve')
```